# Exception deserializing JSON with Newtonsoft sent by CURL to Azure Function

Tags: c#, json, json.net, azure-functions

When posting to my API using CURL the syntax I'm using is:

```
curl -H "Content-Type:application/json" -X POST -d '{"domainName":"fabrikam.onmicrosoft.com","apiKey":"980709a87df09a78dsf90a8s7f"}' http://localhost:7071/api/getnodedata
```

My web API receives the request via:

```
dynamic data = await req.Content.ReadAsAsync<object>();
NodeModel nodeData = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<NodeModel>(data);
```

My class is simple:

```
public class NodeModel : TableEntity
{
    public string DomainName { get; set; }
    public string ApiKey { get; set; }
}

public static NodeModel(string DomainName, string ApiKey)
{
    this.PartitionKey = DomainName;
    this.RowKey = ApiKey;
}
```

Inspecting `data` gives me `'{domainName:fabrikam.onmicrosoft.com,apiKey:980709a87df09a78dsf90a8s7f}'` which looks okay except for the missing double quotes around each key/value pair. CURL is removing the double-quotes before sending it (as verified using Fiddler trace).

I get an exception in my `func.exe` local application as follows:

> mscorlib: Exception while executing function: GetNodeData. Newtonsoft.Json: Error parsing boolean value. Path 'domainName'

I've tried:

1. Spaces between the key/values
2. Single quotes wrapping the keys(s)
3. Single quotes wrapping the value(s)
4. Researching Newtonsoft website for correct syntax
5. Researching this site for other examples (which don't seem to be any different from what I'm doing).

Any suggestions or instructions for using another tool? I have Fiddler too but haven't used it for `POST`ing data to a service.

Comment: what goes over the wire, i mean did the quotes disappear on the sender side or the receiver side

Comment: quotes get stripped on the receiving side. setting a breakpoint in VS along with a watcher for `data` shows the missing inside quotes but outside double-quotes. Odd!

Comment: no, what goes over the wire. use fiddler to see what gets sent. you still do not know where the strip happens

Comment: Can't seem to trace what's being sent from curl using Fiddler. I did some research on using Fiddler instead all up and it's working better. I have another issue but it's not relevant to this question. I could investigate further but I don't know why I can't trace curl from Fiddler.

Comment: `curl` doesn't use a proxy server by default. It probably has a command line option to make it do that.

Comment: Try adding `--proxy http://localhost:8888` and see if it now goes through Fiddler.

Comment: Thanks @DavidG. That was it. I can see the request being stripped of the double quotes leaving only: `'{domainName:fabrikam.onmicrosoft.com,apiKey:980709a87df09a78dsf90a8s7f}'`

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using curl anyway, it's a great tool but if you want to test an API, use Postman for example.

Comment: If you really want to use curl, then post like this: `-d "{\"domainName\": \"fabrikam.onmicrosoft.com\", \"apiKey\": \"980709a87df09a78dsf90a8s7f\"}"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Summarising the comments in an answer...

1. Using Fiddler - this is a great tool, but it works as a proxy server on your machines. Various tools will not respect system settings and `curl` is one of those. The .NET `HttpClient` is the same. So you need to tell it to use the proxy with the `--proxy` (or `-x` for short option:

   ```
   curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '...snip...' http://localhost:7071/api/getnodedata -x http://localhost:8888
   ```
2. `curl` is stripping out the double quotes. To get around that you need to use double quote to surround your data and escape inner quotes with a backslash:

   ```
   -d "{\"domainName\": \"fabrikam.onmicrosoft.com\", \"apiKey\": \"980709a87df09a78dsf90a8s7f\"}"
   ```
3. I wouldn't generally recommend using `curl` to test an API. It's a great tool but, as you have seen, awkward to use. Instead I recommend using [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/).
4. **Bonus!** Your C# code is a little skewy too. Either read the data as a string and pass to JSON.Net:

   ```
   string data = await req.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
   NodeModel nodeData = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<NodeModel>(data);
   ```

   Or, even better, let the extension you're already using do the work for you:

   ```
   NodeModel nodeData = await req.Content.ReadAsAsync<NodeModel>();
   ```

Comment: Great help and nice suggestion on refactoring using .ReadAsStringAsync(). I was using an example online. I'm having issues populating my NodeModel object though. I'll post a separate question on the matter. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
curl -H "Content-Type:application/json" -X POST -d "{\"domainName\":\"fabrikam.onmicrosoft.com\",\"apiKey\":\"980709a87df09a78dsf90a8s7f\"}" 
 http://localhost:7071/api/getnodedata
```